# Semantic-UI tab history activates tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, semantic-ui

I'm using a menu object in Semantic and if I set the tab history state to true, it will always load the page content with a tab activated, despite none of the tabs being active to begin with. The full context source is a big cumbersome but is found [here](https://colinjstevens.com/). As you can see, it loads with the first "About" tab open, despite not containing the `active` class in the tab content's code:
    `<div class="ui tab segment" data-tab="about">`

Some relevant bits:

readyState function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.links.menu .item').tab({
        history : true,
        historyType : 'hash',
    });
    $('.links.menu').transition({
        animation : 'fade down',
        duration : '1s'
    });
});
```

Comment: Try placing `sematic.min.css` reference before `semantic.min.js`.

Comment: Unfortunately moving the order of the imports and such seems to have no effect. I tried ordering it that way and most other combinations that I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

In [the documenation](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab#/usage) it is said that "Tabs use Asual's Address library to provide cross-browser push state support. This is a required dependency for tabs with history to work correctly."
Have you included [the library](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address) in the dependencies ?